# IIS 6 www redirect to non www

Tags: iis, redirect, iis-6, dotnetnuke

We have a Dot net nuke site setup to run on a domain, we would like all http://www.site.com to redirect to just http://site.com.

I can find lots of info for IIS 7 but very little and certainly nothing that has worked for IIS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a 301 permanently moved to your .htaccess file

see http://www.isitebuild.com/301-redirect.htm for a walkthrough

you can also check how some other websites do it: see http://www.blackberryseo.com/seo/header-response-tool1.php and enter "http://www.twitter.com" in the check. They return a "301 Moved" response for that URL.

Comment: IIS doesn't understand .htaccess files; you should configure a second site in the IIS Manager and set it to redirect to the desired URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a htaccess file with an asp.net website.

Have you investigated using a full Url solution for your site?  While you will solve the very simple problems (non www to www), you still have a lot of SEO problems with a DNN site.

Take a look at the Friendly Url Provider that I distribute from my site : [DNN Friendly Url Provider](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Products/Friendly_Url_Provider_For_DNN)

Answer (score 1):

Sort of an old question but in DNN 5 there is another solution if you dont want to muck with DNS and such that i use

its actually a url rewiter hack from Oliver Hine - here is a link to the download http://oliverhine.com/DotNetNuke/CoreModifications/PrimaryPortalAliases.aspx - basically it does a redirect to the first portal alias for that portal so you might have to muck in the db a bit

Answer (score -1):

I just added an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20551799/393089 that addresses how to do this in IIS6. To adapt it to your needs (www to non-www), just make sure your initial site is configured with the non-www domain (i.e. example.com) as the Host Header, then configure the new site with the www domain (i.e. www.example.com) as the Host Header and in the "Redirect to" field, enter your non-www URL with the $S$Q suffix, i.e. http://example.com$S$Q .