# 301 redirect on IIS. Redirect non-www to www

Tags: iis-6

I ought to redirect my website from non-www to www on IIS 6. e.g if I enter domain.com in the url, it has to redirect to www.domain.com for SEO optimization.

I followed the video "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYxabNrIMQ4" for creating my rewrite rule. And I made it as below

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Redirect to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

But it is not working as expected. Help me out to find the solution.

Note: 
My Visual studio shows warning like "The element 'system.webServer' has invalid child element 'rewrite'".

I believe it doesn't make any problem.

Comment: I'd say it's likely that since the video's instructions are for IIS 7.0 (check out 1:52 in the video, you'll see "Internet Information Services 7"), there's something in his instructions that doesn't work with IIS 6.0

Answer (score 2):

According to [this video](http://youtu.be/5_hYRcipt14#t=289) you can redirect using the IIS Manager UI. Make sure you have a second site for the non-WWW version, with the same "Location" as the WWW  version of your site; when creating it, be sure to specify your non-WWW domain for the "Host Header" field.

After creating it, right-click the site and go to Properties. Disable logging if you're so inclined (probably not needed because you'll be redirecting anyways), then go to the "Home Directory" tab. Now remove the Application by clicking the appropriate "Remove" button, since it's not used for redirection. Next, select the "A redirection to a URL" radio button, be sure to check "The exact URL entered above" and "A permanent redirection for this resource".

Lastly, in the "Redirect to" field, enter your full WWW url **followed by $S$Q** (i.e. http://www.example.com$S$Q) -- the $S$Q are important to capture any path and query string the client might send, so if the user goes to http://example.com/foo/bar.html they will be appropriately redirected to http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html instead of just http://www.example.com/ . Click Apply and OK, and your redirection should be set!

Answer (score -1):

Does this works ? remember to add in the root web.config

```
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
```

Comment: How is this any different from what the OP posted?